# Boot problem after running boot repair

Tags: dual-boot

Boot loader did not install on initial installation of Ubuntu 14.04 on a Win 7 machine.  Could not boot to Ubuntu, but could boot to Windows. Ran boot repair tool through Ubuntu start-USB. After completion, cannot boot to Windows. URS for boot report is http://paste.ubuntu.com/15149701/

Comment: Should have noted that computer boots to  what looks like a terminal with a cursor showing >grub 2

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bootable windows device use this to fix mbr so you can boot in to Windows.

There are plenty of guides to fix windows mbr.

Then, use an Ubuntu 15.10 device to install bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

You should restart your system one or two times when you are in Ubuntu. The GRUB boot menu should show, alongside all the other OSes you have installed.

If this is not the case, then open up Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and type in

sudo update-grub

This will update your GRUB boot menu manually and after rebooting, you should be able to see the boot menu.

Comment: I think the issues on sda are confusing grub's update. Grub want to review every drive looking for other operating systems, but sda seems to have several issues. Is it really an internal drive? I might try Boot-Repair's update with it disconnected. And you need to repair sda1. See if Windows chkdsk fixes it or not.

Comment: @oldfred - thanks, I did as you suggested and disconnected sda, which is not an internal drive.  Reran boot repair and got the boot menu.  Can boot into Ubuntu as well as windows now.  have not yet tried to fix sda, but will check that next time I go into windows.  looks like my issue is resolved